# i have error with button share of facebook

Tags: facebook, share

I have link http://muabannhadaklak.com/group/profile/group/9.html, this link work well on my website, but when i share this link on facebook, facebook return error

`Database Error
http://muabannhadaklak.com/group/profile...
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/muabannh/public_html/group/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)`

i don't know why and don't know how to fix this error. My framwork CodeIgniter